# Optimise 'firstOrCreate()' removing first 'select'

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-8

I need to insert a lot of data and sometimes (1% or 2% of `insert`) the data is already present into DB. To manage this 1% or 2% of cases, I'm using the `firstOrCreate()`.

The problem is that using `firstOrCreate()`, *Eloquent* performs always two queries:

- `select`, to check if the data already exists
- `insert`, If the data doesn't exists.

I'd like optimise the code removing first `select` (that returns the Model only on 1% or 2% of data) and the idea is create a code like:

```
try {
    $output = MyModel::create(['field1' => 'value1']);
} catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
    if($e->getCode() == 1062) { // MySQL duplicate key code
        $output = MyModel::where('field1', 'value1')->first();
    }
}
$outputId = $output->id;
```

What is the best practice to do this? Is there an Eloquent method?

Thank you.

Comment: I thing you have the general idea, If you want to avoid the first select query in a use case with way more insert than select. But you should check the performance difference between simple SELCT statement and INSERT. If there is orders of magnitude between them, il might be still beter to perform a quick select to aviod a heavy insert. I don't have the numbers but it's something to think about and benchmark if you need maximum speed / minimum resource consumption

Comment: If you're inserting a lot of data, you may want to check [upsert](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts) It update / insert multiple records with one query.

Comment: `upsert` limitations: https://github.com/mpyw/laravel-retry-on-duplicate-key#differences-from-other-native-upsert-implementations

Comment: The problem of “upsert()” is that if the record exists it “update” the data! But I do not want the update… I want the model from DB.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are no methods like that.

### NOTE

I've already developed the following packages:

- [mpyw/unique-violation-detector: Detect primary/unique key or constraint violation errors from PDOException.](https://github.com/mpyw/unique-violation-detector)
- **[mpyw/laravel-unique-violation-detector: Detect primary/unique key or constraint violation errors from PDOException.](https://github.com/mpyw/laravel-unique-violation-detector)**
- [mpyw/laravel-retry-on-duplicate-key: Automatically retry non-atomic upsert operation when unique key constraints are violated.](https://github.com/mpyw/laravel-retry-on-duplicate-key)

I think these packages are sufficient for general purposes. Reducing SELECT queries might result in so little performance improvements.

However, if you are really willing to provide `INSERT-before-SELECT` optimization, please require `mpyw/laravel-unique-violation-detector` and implement a marco method on Eloquent Builder named like **`createOrFirst()`** to publish it as a package.

###### Example Implementation

```php
<?php

namespace /* ... */;

use Mpyw\LaravelUniqueViolationDetector\Contracts\UniqueViolationDetector;
use /* ... */;

class EloquentCreateOrFirstServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(UniqueViolationDetector $detector): void
    {
        Builder::macro('createOrFirst', function (array $attributes = [], array $values = []) use ($detector): Model {
            \assert($this instanceof Builder);
            return (new CreateOrFirstMacro($detector, $this))($attributes, $values);
        });
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace /* ... */;

use Mpyw\LaravelUniqueViolationDetector\Contracts\UniqueViolationDetector;
use /* ... */;

class CreateOrFirstMacro
{
    public function __construct(
        private UniqueViolationDetector $detector,
        private Builder $query,
    ) {
    }

    public function __invoke(array $attributes = [], array $values = []): Model
    {
        try {
            return (clone $this->query)->create($values + $attributes);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            if ($this->detector->forConnection($this->query->getConnection())->violated($e)) {
                return (clone $this->query)->where($attributes)->firstOrFail();                
            }
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

// _ide_helper.php (barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper format)

if (false) {
    class Eloquent extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
    {
        /**
         * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|static
         */
        public static function createOrFirst(array $attributes = [], array $values)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

###### Example Usage

```php
$model = YourModel::createOrFirst(['field1' => 'value1']);
```

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try it next week. I’ll let you know…

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 10 just added new method for doing that: [createOrFirst](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/47973)